How do you open Google Cloud Shell on macOS Safari?
If you navigate to https://shell.cloud.google.com/?show=ide%2Cterminal page on macOS Safari, then you can't actually see the editor—fails with a We can't load the code editor here because third-party cookies are disabled. error message—see screenshot:

But there's no explanation for how to resolve the error. I tried disabling cookies altogether unchecking the Safari settings > Advanced > Block all cookies setting; but doesn't still doesn't work.
How do you actually load on the https://shell.cloud.google.com/?show=ide%2Cterminal page on macOS Safari? Aside: I know I can switch to Google Chrome; but I'm just curious to actually run the page on Safari.

Google's docs say that it's compatible with Safari 8+ but I'm fairly sure this is false, because I've never successfully got it to work via Safari. I suspect there's an upper limit on the Safari version (whenever they blocked 3rd party cookies by default I suspect).

Have you tried the steps from this thread and this document?
